# Read signed exponential

Tags: fortran, gfortran, exponential

I am having trouble reading exponential from a text file using Fortran.

The entry in the text file looks like the following

```
  0.02547163e+06-0.04601176e+01 0.02500000e+02 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00    3
```

And the code that I am using looks like the following

```
   read(iunit,'(ES20.8,ES20.8,ES20.8,ES20.8,ES20.8,I2)') dummy1, dummy2, Thermo_DB_Coeffs_LowT(iS,1:3),temp
```

The error I am getting is

> Fortran runtime error: Bad value during floating point read

How can I read these values?

Comment: Your field widths for the reals are 20, but that doesn't suit the input.  Can you check that the input is represented correctly here?

Comment: I'd use some text processing utility (eg `sed`) to put spaces into the file where f-p values have run together, then read with *list-directed* input.

Comment: try `15.8`. also I don't think `S` does anything on input, so just `E15.8`. And go have a talk with whoever created such file with numbers run together with no delimiters

Comment: As @agentp says, input with `ES` is treated just like input with `E`.  This is further treated like `F`.  Also, you should prefer not to use `F15.8` but `F15.0` (or whatever field width).

Comment: In general formatted `read`ing should be avoided - it offers nothing and can only cause trouble, depending on the data to be read. I agree with HPF, the data file needs to be modified (by `sed` or a macro in an editor), so that it will separate numbers with spaces (one space would be enough, but you can add more, it doesn't really matter). Then `read(iunit,*)` will just do the job perfectly. While I always use formatted printing, I really can't see any reason to use formatted reading, other than looking for potential trouble.

Comment: `read(iunit,*) ` IS formatted input..  But even without nitpicking, using a format string on input has many good uses.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is what I usually do when it is too painful to hand edit the file...

```
CHARACTER(LEN=256)   :: Line
INTEGER, PARAMETER   :: Start = 1
INTEGER              :: Fin, Trailing_Int, I
DOUBLE, DIMENSION(6) :: Element
...

Ingest_All_Rows: DO WHILE(.TRUE.)
  READ(...) Line  ! Into a character-string
  <if we get to the end of the file, then 'EXIT Ingest_All_Rows'>

  Start =1
  Single_Row_Ingest: DO I = 1, 6
    Fin = SCAN(Line,'eE')+3  !or maybe it is 4?
    IF(I ==6) Fin = LEN_TRIM(Line)
    READ(Line(Start:Fin),*) Element(I)   !fron the string(len-string) to the double.
    Line = Line((Fin+1):)
    IF(I ==6) Trailing_Int = Element(6)
  ENDDO Single_Row_Ingest

  <Here we shove the row's 5 elements into some array, and the trailing int somewhere>
ENDDO Ingest_All_Rows
```

You will have to fill in the blanks, but I find that SCAN and LEN_TRIM can be useful in these cases